# ASP.NET "auth" cookie value changes, but old value remains valid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, slidingexpiration

I have a ASP.NET MVC application using form authentication.

When the user logs in, then I get an `auth` cookie set to some value. I.E.:

```
auth = XXXYYY001
```

All good.

Now, when half the session expiration time passes (as stated in the documentation) when sliding expiration session is enabled, the `auth` cookie value changes.

```
auth = XXXYYY002
```

I have no problem with this.

The problem is that the original cookie value (`XXXYYY001`) still works when I try to hijack the session from a different browser after the `auth` cookie value changed. This was flagged by an ethical hacking work we had on out site and I was able to reproduce it on a simple test site I built.

My question is: how could I prevent this from happening? I haven't look at the source code (I don't even know if that ASP.NET's part is open source) but I haven't found anything in the documentation telling me how to handle this scenario.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Let the original expiration time elapse and the original cookie will no longer work.